# How can I speed up Rails Docker deployments on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-app-engine, docker, dockerfile

I'm experimenting with more cost effective ways to deploy my Rails apps, and went through the [Ruby Starter Projects](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/hello-world) to get a feel for Google Cloud Platform.

It's *almost* perfect, and certainly competitive on price, but the deployments are incredibly slow.

When I run the deployment command from [the sample Bookshelf app](https://cloud.google.com/ruby/getting-started/tutorial-app):

```
$ gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml worker.yaml --promote
```

I can see a new `gae-builder-vm` instance on the [Compute Engine/VM Instances page](https://console.developers.google.com/compute/instances) and I get [the familiar Docker build output](https://gist.github.com/christiangenco/c3d84119bf7c594b7bd6#file-output-of-first-gcloud-deploy-txt) - this takes about ten minutes to finish.

If I immediately redeploy, though, I get a new `gae-builder-vm` spun up that goes through [the exact same ten-minute build process with no apparent caching from the first time the image was built](https://gist.github.com/christiangenco/c3d84119bf7c594b7bd6#file-output-of-second-gcloud-deploy-txt).

In both cases, the second *module* (worker.yaml) gets cached and goes really quickly:

```
Building and pushing image for module [worker]
---------------------------------------- DOCKER BUILD OUTPUT ----------------------------------------
Step 0 : FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/ruby
---> 3e8b286df835
Step 1 : RUN rbenv install -s 2.2.3 &&     rbenv global 2.2.3 &&     gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler --version 1.10.6 &&     gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri foreman --version 0.78.0
---> Using cache
---> efdafde40bf8
Step 2 : ENV RBENV_VERSION 2.2.3
---> Using cache
---> 49534db5b7eb
Step 3 : COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/
---> Using cache
---> d8c2f1c5a44b
Step 4 : RUN bundle install && rbenv rehash
---> Using cache
---> d9f9b57ccbad
Step 5 : COPY . /app/
---> Using cache
---> 503904327f13
Step 6 : ENTRYPOINT bundle exec foreman start --formation "$FORMATION"
---> Using cache
---> af547f521411
Successfully built af547f521411
```

but it doesn't make sense to me that these versions couldn't be cached between deployments if nothing has changed.

Ideally I'm thinking this would go faster if I triggered a rebuild on a dedicated build server (which could remember Docker images between builds), which then updated a public image file and asked Google to redeploy with the prebuilt image, which would go faster.

Here's the Docker file that was generated by `gcloud`:

```
# This Dockerfile for a Ruby application was generated by gcloud with:
# gcloud preview app gen-config --custom

# The base Dockerfile installs:
# * A number of packages needed by the Ruby runtime and by gems
#   commonly used in Ruby web apps (such as libsqlite3)
# * A recent version of NodeJS
# * A recent version of the standard Ruby runtime to use by default
# * The bundler and foreman gems
FROM gcr.io/google_appengine/ruby

# Install ruby 2.2.3 if not already preinstalled by the base image
# base image: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/ruby-docker/blob/master/appengine/Dockerfile
# preinstalled ruby versions: 2.0.0-p647 2.1.7 2.2.3
RUN rbenv install -s 2.2.3 && \
    rbenv global 2.2.3 && \
    gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri bundler --version 1.10.6 && \
    gem install -q --no-rdoc --no-ri foreman --version 0.78.0
ENV RBENV_VERSION 2.2.3

# To install additional packages needed by your gems, uncomment
# the "RUN apt-get update" and "RUN apt-get install" lines below
# and specify your packages.
# RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt-get install -y -q (your packages here)

# Install required gems.
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /app/
RUN bundle install && rbenv rehash

# Start application on port 8080.
COPY . /app/
ENTRYPOINT bundle exec foreman start --formation "$FORMATION"
```

How can I make this process faster?

Comment: Did you figure out a way to speed things up? My deployments are painfully slow at the moment

Comment: Nope - I ended up using [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku) on cheap VPS boxes. It was easier to set up than GAE, and just as easy/fast to deploy to as Heroku (just a `git push`, and the VM remembers its installed gems).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you're kinda mixing up 2 different cases:

- re-deploying the **exact same** app code - indeed Google doesn't check if there was any change in the app to be deployed in which case the entire docker image could be re-used - but you already have that image, effectively you don't even need to re-deploy. Unless you suspect something went wrong and you really insist on re-building the image (and the deployment utility does exactly that). A rather academic case with little bearing to cost-effectiveness of real-life app deployments :)
- you're deploying a **different** app code (doesn't matter how much different) - well, short of re-using the cached artifacts during the image building (which happens, according to your build logs) - the final image still needs to be built to incorporate the new app code - unavoidable. Re-using the previously built image is not really possible.

**Update:** I missed your point earlier, upon a closer look at both your logs I agree with your observation that the cache seems to be local to each build VM (explained by the cache hits only during building the `worker` modules, each on the same VM where the corresponding `default` module was built beforehand) and thus not re-used across deployments.

**Another Update**: there *might* be a way to get cache hits across deployments...

The [`gcloud preview app deploy` DESCRIPTION](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/app/deploy) indicates that the hosted build could also be done using the Container Builder API (which appears to be **the default setting**!) in addition to a temporary VM:

> To use a temporary VM (with the default --docker-build=remote
>   setting), rather than the Container Builder API to perform docker
>   builds, run:
>
> ```
> $ gcloud config set app/use_cloud_build false
> ```

Builds done using the [Container Builder API](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/) *might* use a shared storage, which *might* allow cache hits across deployments. IMHO it's worth a try.