# Google Cloud deploy so slow

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using Google Cloud NodeJS hosting. 
I'm so surprised when I deploy apps to Google Cloud. It's very slow for each deployment.
It could be slow the first time, but after that, when I change some js or html file and re-deploy, it is still slow.

Does it take 5~10 minutes to deploy a small project?
How could I speed it up?

Comment: Certain cloud functions take me over 40 minutes to deploy. Pretty bad service at times.

Answer (score 7):

The nodejs apps use flexible environment based on docker files which take time to create/update. See [How can I speed up Rails Docker deployments on Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500213/how-can-i-speed-up-rails-docker-deployments-on-google-cloud-platform/36677210#36677210)

Also, when re-deploying the same version some additional time is required to update the service, see [why does google appengine deployment take several minutes to update service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40205222/why-does-google-appengine-deployment-take-several-minutes-to-update-service)

Potentially of interest as well:

- [google app engine deploy a custom vm app takes a long time to deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40510772/google-app-engine-deploy-a-custom-vm-app-takes-a-long-time-to-deploy/40511366#40511366)