# why does google appengine deployment take several minutes to update service

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm using nodejs flexible environment documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml)

Nothing fancy in the config

```
runtime: nodejs
vm: true
service: SimpleExpressService
health_check:
  enable_health_check: False
automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 4
  cool_down_period_sec: 120
  cpu_utilization:
    target_utilization: 0.5
```

Here is my deployment command

```
gcloud app deploy -q --promote --version $VER
```

Whenever I deploy a new version, almost everything goes really fast. However, the step 'Updating service [SimpleExpressServer]' takes several minutes.

Is there anyway to optimize this step?

[image]

Comment: This is pretty dire. I actually thought the step had crashed after about 10 minutes. I was just updating `package.json`.

Comment: Still so slow, I thought Google had cutting edge tech...

Answer (score 12):

From [Deploying your program](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/testing-and-deploying-your-app):

> By default the deploy command automatically generates a new version ID
>   each time that you use it and will route any traffic to the new
>   version.
>
> To override this behavior, you can specify the version ID with the
>   version flag:
>
> ```
> gcloud app deploy --version myID
> ```
>
> You can also specify not to send all traffic to the new version
>   immediately with the --no-promote flag:
>
> ```
> gcloud app deploy --no-promote
> ```

So your deployment includes overwriting the specified app version and switching traffic to the newly deployed version.

When you re-deploy a certain version there's a pile of **additional** stuff to be done compared to the 1st deployment of that version, which includes at least:

- switching traffic away from the version being overwritten
- shutting down the instances running the previous version of the code:

  - determining the scaling type
  - finding out which are the running instances
  - any grace period to complete requests in progress
  - any grace period to complete shutdown hooks (if applicable)
  - sending them the `/_ah/stop` request
- decomissioning the old vm instances

Comment: Thanks. I understand the process, so, this 10+ mins to do all these is set in stone or are there any config settings that can help us to shorten the time?

Comment: None that I know of.

Comment: There is literally no reason for this step to be so long. now.sh does it in under 30s!! https://twitter.com/rauchg/status/834222303105867777

Comment: @stanm87 That may be true for *that particular* app case at *that time*. But it doesn't mean it's always gonna take ~30s for *every other* app deployment.

Comment: @DanCornilescu of course, but GAE doesn't have any case at any time that is that fast. GAE baseline is 7min to just to update a freakin service, that runs on 1 smallest machine (manual scaling), without any building (docker image already built and pushed to their registry)

Comment: @stanm87 That may be true, but it is, after all, just hearsay - unless (you actually work there and) you *know exactly* the details of everything that can be happening in the GAE infra at deployment time.

Comment: Or if there is an SLA documenting a minimum (or maybe even a typical or max) deployment type figure.

Comment: Deployment time on GCP is still very slow ? No new options ? I tried Azure AppServices and it deploys immediately after copying (0 seconds). Deployment time on GCP is one of the weaknesses