# Deployment of Vuejs - webpack webapp on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment, webpack, vue.js

I am building my first Vue.js webapp.
I have setup a new project by using:

```
vue init webpack <project_name>
```

I have done some work and almost everything works as I want (except for sass but that's a story for another time).
I now want to deploy my webapp to google app engine.
I have created a new node.js project on GAE.
I've created my app.yaml (see below).
I deploy with the usual

```
gcloud app deploy --project="<project_name>"
```

but then the deployment fails after a very long time (~5-8minutes) saying

```
Updating service [default]...failed.                                                                                                                   

ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Your deployment has 
failed to become healthy in the allotted time and therefore was 
rolled back. If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the 
'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section.
```

My current project structure is:

- build/
- config/
- dist/

  - index.html
  - static

    - css/
    - images/
    - js/
- node modules/
- src/

  - components/
  - scss/
  - App.vue
  - main.js
- static/
- package.json
- babel.rc
- index.html
- app.yaml

My app.yaml is:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this config in file app.yaml

```
runtime: php55
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: dist/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1
  upload: dist/(.*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates:

> Your deployment has failed to become healthy in the allotted time

Go through the [Health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks) documentation.

The 5-8 minutes deploying time is not unusual, see [Google cloud deploy so slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200467/google-cloud-deploy-so-slow).