# Why does an App Engine deployment take 15 minutes? (And the problem with pub/sub)

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to deploy [spring-boot hellow world example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-try-java), and when the build is done, I still need to wait about 15 minutes. In the console I just see

[image: Done]

After that I try to deploy [pub/sub example](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gcp/tree/master/spring-cloud-gcp-samples/spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-sample), and after 15 minutes I get the error message:

> "If you believe this was an error, try adjusting the
>   'app_start_timeout_sec' setting in the 'readiness_check' section".

I tried to set this variable to 10 sec, and 1800(max value), but it didn't help.

This is my app.yaml

```
runtime: java
env: flex
version: v1

runtime_config:  # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

I use the appengine-maven-plugin to deploy

Comment: I can't tell from your image if the build included the dockerfile creation, if it doesn't this may be of use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200467/google-cloud-deploy-so-slow/40218677#40218677

Comment: Yes, it uses the docker
`[INFO] GCLOUD: Step #0: INFO  - Using base image 'gcr.io/google-appengine/openjdk@sha256:f282097002efdc110b6fb82a20d71d2a8b4e38c10363a5ce353b0f8e653bbfa2' for JAR artifact
[INFO] GCLOUD: Step #0: INFO  - Generating Dockerfile at /workspace/Dockerfile
[INFO] GCLOUD: Step #0: INFO  - Generating .dockerignore file at /workspace/.dockerignore`

Comment: It seems like your deployment attempt is failing at [health checks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml#health_checks). Since your app.yaml did not include the section for 'readiness_check', can you confirm this is what you've tried to add in your previous attempts?