# Can I update only app.yaml file without uploading all project

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Is there a way to update selected files when using the App Engine Flexible env?

I'm facing an issue whenever I do a small change in the app.yaml file: to test it I would need to deploy the whole application which takes ~5mins.

Is there a way to update only the config file? OR is there a way to test these files locally.

Thanks!

Comment: potentially of interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500213/how-can-i-speed-up-rails-docker-deployments-on-google-cloud-platform/36677210#36677210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The safe/blanket answer would be **no** as the flex env docker image would need to be updated regardless of how tiny the changes are, see [How can I speed up Rails Docker deployments on Google Cloud Platform?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34500213/how-can-i-speed-up-rails-docker-deployments-on-google-cloud-platform/36677210#36677210)

However, there *might* be something to try (YMMV).

From [App Engine Flexible Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/):

> - You always have root access to Compute Engine VM instances. SSH access to VM instances in the flexible environment is disabled by
>     default. If you choose, you can enable root access to your app's VM
>     instances.

So you *might* be able to login as root on your GAE instance VM and try to manually modify a particular app artifact. Of course, you'd need to locate the artifact first.

Some artifacts *might* not even be present in the VM image itself (those used exclusively by the GAE infra, queue definitions, for example). But it *should* be possible to update these artifacts without updating the docker image, since they aren't part of the flex env service itself.

Other artifacts *might* be read-only and it *might* not be possible to change them to read-write.

Even if possible, such manual changes would be volatile, they would not survive an instance reload (which would be using the **unmodified** docker image), which *might* be required for some changes to take effect.

Lots of "might"s, lots of risks (manual fiddling with the app code could negatively impact its functionality), up to you to determine if a try is really worthy.

**Update:** it seems this is actually documented and supported, see [Accessing Google App Engine Python App code in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253187/accessing-google-app-engine-python-app-code-in-production)