# Where are appengine projects located normally in the file system of the server via ssh?

Tags: google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, google-cloud-platform

I have a standard java based web application and I have someone who wants to take a look at it and possibly change a file or add a file via ssh. But we cannot locate the project folder of the appengine project in Google's cloud shell. So where exactly are app engine project files normally located?

Comment: Standard or flex env?

Comment: Standard sorry should have mentioned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot directly access the app's files from the cloud shell because the cloud shell doesn't run on the same instance as your app code.

In the standard environment you also can't access the actual instance executing the app code (this is [possible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/debugging-an-instance) in the flexible environment), see also [Accessing Google App Engine Python App code in production](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253187/accessing-google-app-engine-python-app-code-in-production).

You can view the live/deployed version of your app service code using StackDriver, as described in [Google Cloud DataStore automatic indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47498821/google-cloud-datastore-automatic-indexing/47499884#47499884). From that viewer StackDriver also allows debugging/inspecting the live code:

[image]

AFAIK you cannot change the live code, you need to deploy an updated version of the code for that.

Comment: I assumed this might have been the case. Brilliant, thank you!