# Google App Engine CLI - list project directory

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, google-cloud-shell

Is there a way to print the contents of my project directory using the google app engine cloud shell?

In my local terminal that would look like typing 'ls'

What command would I use in the shell?

Answer (score 1):

The cloud shell is fundamentally just a shell running on a **generic** virtual machine in the cloud.

That machine does NOT have any special attributes (compared to your local machine) except maybe that it comes with some tools (like the google cloud SDK) already installed. It has no implicit knowledge about or access to your cloud products/projects themselves.

So, by default, the cloud shell doesn't know which/where your GAE project is. You'd have to pull a copy of your project repository/code on that instance and, when in that project's directory, you could list the project's content using `ls`, just like on your local machine. See also the somehow related [Google Cloud: How to deploy mirrored Repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42122249/google-cloud-how-to-deploy-mirrored-repository/42123320#42123320)

The machine on which the cloud shell runs is also unrelated to the instances on which GAE apps are running, so you can't directly list on it the directory content of the *actually deployed* GAE project. If that's what you're after see [Where are appengine projects located normally in the file system of the server via ssh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50350813/where-are-appengine-projects-located-normally-in-the-file-system-of-the-server-v/50352450#50352450)